# How do I get output on same line

Tags: java, format

I need to write a program where the output will be on the same line as the input. I have tried print() and println() but they come out the same. What do I need to add?

```
String str= scanner.next();
System.out.println("    donut");
```

the output is (if I were to type in apple)

```
apple
    donut
```

but I want it to print

```
apple   donut
```

Comment: `print` instead of `println` (`System.out.print("    donut");`)

Comment: @GBlodgett I think the OP was misunderstood (or only I did not understand the question). S/He is asking about how to print  `donut` in the same line where the user entered `apple`. I don't think `print` solves that, does it? Am I missing something here?

Comment: You could get it to print `apple donut` by doing `System.out.println(str + "   donut");` but your initial input of apple would still be above the printed output.

Comment: @DrZoo is correct. That was my initial though as well. I only considered the other idea I explained below after seeing what the OP was printing with `System.out.println("    donut");`, which does not includes `str`.

Comment: Sorry if the wording was weird, I didn't know how to word it good but @lealceldeiro answered it spot on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot simply do that. The line where the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is waiting for an input is not used for printing. Once you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the position in the console moves to the next line, where is printed what you put inside (`print`, `println`, etc).

This is a different matter, not related to whether you want to print some tokens in the same line or not, in which case using `System.out.print`/`println` would solve the problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks. The program I'm writing wants the output set up like that but I guess I'll have to do it another way.